# Spring Boot 2.5.6 catch 22 with spring.profiles.active

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am updating a web app from Spring Boot 2.2.4 to 2.5.6 and have used Open Rewrite to handle the tedium. The run configuration in IntelliJ has `spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=local -f pom.xml` in the command line (this has been working with 2.2.4). After adding a try/catch to main, to actually learn why I kept getting exit code 1 with no additional info, I found `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.profiles.active' in value "classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"` to be the root issue.

Apparently passing `local` on the command line for `spring.profiles.active` is now ignored… So, I added it to `application.yml` which gives me a message about how it is invalid to use `spring.profiles.active`. I found that the currently active profile should now be in `config.activate.on-profile.active` so I switched to that and then did a project wide search for `spring.profiles.active` and replaced *every single* instance with `config.activate.on-profile.active`.

I ran the project again and again got the message that it could resolve the placeholder `spring.profiles.active`! I can't for the life of me figure out where that placeholder is coming from since it doesn't exist anywhere in the project now according to IntelliJ, not even in the ReadMe file!

Is there some secret place I need to look to purge this old placeholder from existence?

Comment: **don't!!** [Today, `2.5.7` has been released](https://spring.io/blog/2021/11/18/spring-boot-2-5-7-is-now-available)! xDxD

Comment: Thanks! Pretty sure I'll still have this issue though…

Comment: yaa... :-( 1. best: locate why & where this `${spring.profiles.active}` was not resolved. 2. `config.activate.on-profile.active` is definitely *"out"* 3. [Read this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Config-Data-Migration-Guide) ...and if we still don't find it, then we also need to go through..

Comment: ..the "upgrading from ..." sections of [2.3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes), 2.4, 2.5 release notes ;(

Comment: I am facing the same problem, were you able to find a solution for the issue

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and found a [link to a github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21631) where a workaround was provided.
Create a class:

```
public class JunitProfileResolver implements ActiveProfilesResolver {

  private static final String PROFILE_JUNIT = "test";

  @Override
  public String[] resolve(Class<?> testClass) {
    System.setProperty(AbstractEnvironment.ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME, PROFILE_JUNIT);
    return new String[] { PROFILE_JUNIT };
  }
}
```

And use it like:

```
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test", resolver = JunitProfileResolver.class)
public class MyTest {
```

For me this solves the problem.